# How to set up Angular with Mongodb for search?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, search

I am trying to figure out how to make my MongoDB data searchable using Angular. Currently I have managed to accomplish a searchable Angular app with hard coded data but I have been unable to figure out how to pass my MongoDB data into my Angular set up. In the code below I show the Angular search set up with example data and then my MongoDB model set up at the bottom.

My question is: How would I go about displaying my MongoDB data instead of the array I currently have set up? Thanks for any help!!

```
var app = angular.module('dreamjob', []);
app.controller('JobsController', function ($scope){  


$scope.search = {};
$scope.selectedIndex = null;
$scope.selectedPerson = null;


$scope.jobs = [
        {
            "name": "Gregory Huffman",
            "email": "Praesent@pedenec.net",
            "birthdate": "2015-03-23T18:00:37-07:00",
            "phonenumber": "07624 073918",
            "address": "5880 Sed, Street",
            "city": "Denderbelle",
            "country": "Ethiopia"
        },
        {
            "name": "Tad Vazquez",
            "email": "dapibus.gravida@necimperdietnec.co.uk",
            "birthdate": "2015-12-28T06:02:56-08:00",
            "phonenumber": "(016977) 1036",
            "address": "830-6354 Cubilia Rd.",
            "city": "Sulzbach",
            "country": "Liechtenstein"
        },
]
```

})

```
<div class="form-group" >
                        <input type="text"
                               class="form-control"
                               id="name"
                               ng-model="search"
                               placeholder="Search name..."
                                />
                </div >
            </form >

        </div >
    </div >
<table class="table table-bordered">

<tr>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>email</th>
    <th>Birthdate</th>
</tr>

<tr ng-repeat="job in jobs | filter: search">
    <td> {{job.name}} </td>
    <td> {{job.email}} </td>
    <td> {{job.birthdate}} </td>
</tr>
</table>

</div>
```

MONGO

```
var jobSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   name: String,
   image: String,
   description: String,
   position: String,
   location: String,
   pay: String,
```

Comment: Angular cannot directly talk to Mongo. Where is your server code?

Comment: You need to use `$http` to send ajax request to server

Comment: Hey @charlietfl can you give me a little more detail on how I would do that?

Comment: Sure...read the angular $http docs. Look for angular form tutorials

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: First thing is you need to have a backend application which provides you an api to get the data from mongodb. Do you have that?